# Custom option File upload getting in order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options

I have a custom option for image upload on product page I just want to know how can i get this image in customer order.

There is by default functionality which gives you link but it redirect on dashboard but I want to download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer Its due to enable the “**Add Store Code to Urls**” in System -> Configuration -> General -> Web

Just **Disable** it. You Got an image to download in order.

For magento version 1.7 and below version

Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the order details page in the backend (Sales->Orders->Select order to view) you should see below the items that support file upload a link to download the file.  Click on that.

[image: Upload sample]

Comment: Yeah its right but when i click on that link it redirect me on dashboard of admin panel not able to download image.

Comment: That's strange. It worked for me.

Comment: Ok Thanks Marius. But now any suggestion for what can i do to get image ?

Comment: I don't know. Like I said. It worked for me. You can try with a different image. Maybe there is something wrong with that one. Maybe it doesn't get saved on your file system. Check var/log for errors.

Comment: Ok thanks Marius ... I have More one Question if you have don't mind.

Comment: Can be an alternate, you can try to show source of image in a small view, instead of the link. I mean bit of over riding the default

Comment: @Marius Same issue for me. when i click on file link it redirect on home page. 
issue is in url. i have two website with one magneto. 

1) ab.xyz.com and
2) pq.xyz.com while 

admin url is xyz.com/index.php/admin 

if in default config Sytem > configuration > general > web > Base url change with ab.xyz.com/pq.xyz.com(any one from this two) from xyz.com then order view file link works fine.

I want to keep admin url xyz.com instead of ab.xyz.com how it is possible? 
Thanks in advance