# Magento Custom option file download 404 page in order

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file, download-link, magento-1.9.3.3

After upgrade `1.9.2.4` to `1.9.3.3`.
I have some issue regarding to order.
When I clicked custom option type file for download I got 404 page.

When I tried to print log related to file following code return in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php`.
in `_getOptionHtml($optionValue)`.

```
Array
(
    [type] => image/png
    [title] => Chimp logo vector WITHOUT R.png
    [quote_path] => /media/custom_options/quote/C/h/0d82ed5bd0ebc6ef699da24c5086ac49.png
    [order_path] => /media/custom_options/order/C/h/0d82ed5bd0ebc6ef699da24c5086ac49.png
    [fullpath] => /home/ddfgbbtgfbtttb/public_html/media/custom_options/quote/C/h/0d82ed5bd0ebc6ef699da24c5086ac49.png
    [size] => 47115
    [width] => 1438
    [height] => 809
    [secret_key] => 0d82ed5bd0ebc6ef699d
    [url] => Array
        (
            [route] => sales/download/downloadCustomOption
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1999
                    [key] => 0d82ed5bd0ebc6ef699d
                )

        )

)
```

I also refer following links [One](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22128/custom-option-file-upload-getting-in-order) 
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830947/custom-option-file-download-from-sales-orders-page-in-admin-not-working-in-mage#), 
Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @Andras not yet